# How to remove Privacy settings popup from flash player?

Tags: flash, red5

I am using red5 server for video recording. But when using for video recording, it shows Privacy popup for allowing Camera and microphone for recording 
I want it should allow always. How do I proceed further 
Your help will be appreciable

Thank you

Comment: Can you show code? What have you tried? Will https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html work?

Comment: No I have not done coding with this I am using demos of Red5

Comment: @user3368514 Alexander and Mondain's answers are correct.  There are a couple of different ways to get around this on the client, not all of which are obvious, but your Flash code can't do anything about it.

That's for Flash Player, of course.  If you compile it for Adobe AIR and have it installed as a desktop application / mobile app, they won't ever see that message.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove that pop-up via client nor server side code; it is built into FlashPlayer. A n individual may prevent some pop-ups from showing for specifically selected sites via their FlashPlayer settings panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that popup, but you can instruct the users of your application to visit [Website Privacy Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) for the Flash Player, select your server in the list and set "Always Allow".